# Can sql server logins stored in the master db/jobs in msdb be used for migration using database backup/restore to another sql server (same version)?

Tags: sql-server

In sql server when we expand security, expand logins, there is list of logins. These are stored in the master db.

So, when migrating to another server (same SQL version), if we backup this master db and restore to the new server, then will the logins get migrated to the new server?

Similarly SQL server jobs, schedules, etc are stored in the msdb? Can master and msdb be backup/restored to migrate the logins and jobs to the new server?

I have tried both of thr above, but not able to find any msdn reference about this.

Or is master/msdb backup only meant to be restored onto the same server when those dbs get corrupt?

Comment: We do have FCI/AG for most servers for HADR. But I'm trying to understand about using the master/msdb backup/restore on another server approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply answering your questions is not the solution to your questions.

> **Q: Are all these stored in the master db?**

**Yes.** (Well sort of)

> **Q: If so, then when migrating to another server, if we backup this master db and restore to the new server, then will the logins get migrated to the new server?**

**Yes & No** The logins would be in the database, but so would other information. It is recommended to transfer the SQL Server Logins using the procedure documented by Microsoft. See also the Q&A [Transfer logins to another server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/47378/15356).

One of the reasons for this is listed in the quote below.

<sub>(**emphasis** mine)</sub>

> In the event of disaster recovery, the instance where the master database is being restored to should be as close to an exact match to the original as possible. **At a minimum, this recovery instance should be the same version, edition, and patch level**, and it should have the same selection of features and the same external configuration (**hostname**, cluster membership, and so on) as the original instance. **Doing otherwise might result in undefined SQL Server instance behavior**, with inconsistent feature support, and is not guaranteed to be viable.

<sup>...taken from _[Restore the master Database (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-the-master-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) (SQL Docs)</sup>

Essentially, you could restore the master database, but would invalidate other information. Hence the recommendation to use the migration script to transfer logins.

**Restoring the master database from one instance to another can break the whole instance.**

> **Q:  Similarly SQL server jobs, schedules, etc are stored in the msdb? Can this be backup/restored to migrate the jobs to the new server?**

I would also recommend to right-click the jobs and script them out to ensure they are created correctly on the new server.

Even though the **msdb** database is slightly less relevant for a functioning SQL Server instance, the newer versioned msdb could still contain elements (columns, tables, ...) that are not available in older versions.

In a **same version** scenario, you could **possibly** (no guarantees given) use a backup of the **msdb** database to have the jobs transferred, however, you would have to verify that you do not invalidate jobs, that were created during the installation process of the newer SQL Server instance.

> **Q: If not, then what is the purpose of doing a backup of these system dbs?**

When your server system crashes and you want to restore the whole SQL Server instance in place, then you would require the **master** database to restore all the databases, logins, etc. and the **msdb** database to have all the jobs back.

Comment: Would be nice to add the point about local windows users being different.

Comment: Yes, but that would be a different question. That is why I removed my comment on your new question and upvoted mbuschis answer. I'll add an additional answer to your new question, to show you how you can manually work around such an issue. But I'll have to test it first. On a side-note: It would be nice if you could accept answers that answer your questions and solve the outlined issues. It is appreciation towards the community members.

Comment: I still think it is a relevant point to be added into this answer, maybe as a side note for the benefit of others.